# Monitor with mini display output into thunderboldt to USB-C adaptor

Tags: display, thunderbolt, displayport

Staying somewhere and having trouble using their monitor which has a mini-display input. I have a thunderbolt to USB-C converter which the mini display fits perfectly into (see picture). But it doesn't seem to be working. Should this work, is mini-display compatible with my convertor? Thought I'd ask here first before I go out and buy a new cable.

[image: Monitor input]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not supposed to work. The adapter does not support connecting mini-DisplayPort monitors. It will only work with Thunderbolt monitors such as the Apple Thunderbolt Display or the LG Thunderbolt 2 monitors.

Comment: Thanks! Best head to the store then.

Comment: There will be Thunderbolt adapters with USB-C to mini-DP and DisplayPort adapters with USB-C to mini-DP,  in spite of being so similar physically they are quite different electronically.